# Is there Intergender wrestling at the college level?

Tags: collegiate, gender, wrestling

Is there intergender wrestling at the college level? Who usually wins, men or women?

Comment: You have asked a [similar question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/22516/intergender-amateur-wrestling-and-boxing) before. Please don't re-post unanswered questions. This won't help getting them answered.

Comment: @dly I actually find this question more specific and less broad. OP, editing the previous question would have been the more preferred course of action.

Comment: [This](https://www.chicagotribune.com/sports/ct-spt-girl-wrestler-high-school-forfeit-20190301-story.html) is an insightful article. In Colorado, since high school female wrestling is not sanctioned, females are welcome to wrestle against males. Two female wrestlers the article mentions placed fourth and fifth at a tournament.